# Using PHP and Javascript to animate Download button

Tags: javascript, php, animation

My PHP based web app has an "export" button that works. [This is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkqA3.png). What I want to do is, once the data is exported then change that icon to a green checkbox. My PHP code on notes.php looks like:

```
if(isset($_POST['export_notes_to_excel'])){
  $sql_for_export = explode("ORDER", $_SESSION['sql']);
  $sql_for_export = $sql_for_export[0];
  $filename = "Notes Exported On - " .date('Y-m-d');
  $column_names = array("[Id]" => "ID", "[DateAdded]"=>"Date Added", "[Entry]"=>"Enty", "[AddedBy_Id]"=>"Officer ID");
  export_sql_to_excel($sql_for_export, $filename,$column_names);
}
```

This code works fine and I was trying to use JS here but the problem is PHP does not render my JS if I do something like:

```
echo "<script>console.log('test');</script>";
```

after the export_sql_to_excel() function call. I wanted to do 2 things actually. First, change that download icon to a loading icon when the file is being prepared by PHP and then a checkbox icon once the file is downloaded. Any help would be appreciated. Can this even be done with PHP being the server side code?
Thank you.

Comment: call php via ajax with js-return and update your document

Comment: Seconded for AJAX. Create a hidden div with an id then create 2 css classes 1 for loading & 1 for the checkbox/tick. Add an id to the submit button and then when clicked you'll be able to hide it using js. Then unhide the hidden div and add the loading icon class to it. Then comes your AJAX: get JSON response & change the class on the div to the checkbox/tick.

Comment: Thank you very much for the idea. While the JS side did work and now I can change the icons, what does not work now is the actual downloading of the excel file. Here is the ajax code that I use to send the POST request to notes.php: 
`//send the ajax request
$request = $.ajax({ 
url : "/CampusPolice2/notes.php",
type: "POST",
data : {export_notes_to_excel : 'a'}
 });`
On notes.php I have the exact PHP code that is in my original question. Problem is that, PHP does not recognize the AJAX request or something. It just doesn't work anymore. Thank you.